# TFS 2015 Error Warehouse build

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-reports

after migrate from TFS 2013 to TFS 2015 update 3 we got this error when trying to manually recreate cube for reports.

```
[Work Item Tracking Warehouse Sync]: ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseException: 
TF221122: An error occurred running job Work Item Tracking Warehouse Sync for team project collection
 or Team Foundation server tfs_collection. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.Metadata.
WorkItemTrackingTreeNodeNotFoundException: TF51541: The Node ID is not recognized: 1310 at Microsoft.
```

This error occurs for work item **tracking warehouse sync**.
We had rebuild cube, still the same issue.
Did you ever meet with this TFS issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error message and error ID *TF221122*& *TF51541*,TFS version:

> This issue is marked as a **known issue**. However, we need to validate
>   whether you are hitting the same scenario/known issue. In order to do
>   that please use the following select queries, and if you get any
>   result data, please contact the Microsoft support using the support
>   options provided at  www.support.microsoft.com

More details please refer this blog from TFS Support Team: [TF51541: The Node ID is not recognized](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/05/13/tf51541-the-node-id-is-not-recognized/).